# regex for extracting only alphabets and numbers in a string in R

Tags: regex, r

Hi I need a regex which extracts numbers and (numbers + alphabets) if present in a string.

Ex: "4596 2B FC JAIN BHAWAN" --> I want "4596 2B" as my output

```
> gsub("\\S([a-zA-Z])+\\S", "", "4596 2B FC JAIN BHAWAN")
[1] "4596 2B FC  "
```

I do not understand why the above regex did not replace FC with ""

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `\\S` (capital) which means "not a space", use the lower case, and only use it once (because the end of your string doesn't terminate with a space):

```
gsub("\\s([a-zA-Z])+", "", "4596 2B FC JAIN BHAWAN")
```

Using Simon's suggestion allows us to see the woods for the trees:

```
gsub("\\b[a-zA-Z]+\\b", "", "aa 4592 2B FC JAIN BHAWAN")
[1] " 4592 2B"
```

though I might need some help to get rid of the initial space. (I could just put nested `gsub`s but that seems cheating.)

Comment: Note that if your string starts with e.g. `aa 45 jfk3`, it will keep the `aa`. I'll make an edit

Comment: How about using `\\b` after the `+` to safely match the empty string at the end of a word (which works with words at the start and end of lines). Also the `()` capture group is unnecessary.

Comment: still leaves a nasty space at the start. This will do it `"(\\b|\\s)[a-zA-Z]+(\\b|\\s)"`

Comment: @JeremyS yeah, that'll do nicely.

Comment: It's not clear that the space should be omitted, though. In his example, OP leaves spaces in.